# Displaying reset button in signing identities ios development

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl-certificate

I have created an application, For this app I have created all certificate, installed in xCode, but it is showing not matching provisional profile found error.

When I opened my xCode/account there in signing identities IOS development and IOS distribution it is showing reset button, If I will click reset in development reset, it will affect all other application which is created with certificate?

If I copied my app into another mac there it is not showing any error.

Anyone suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If On other mac all certificates work fine and app run then make the .p12 file of that certificate on that MAC and install it on your MAC. The problem will resolve.

Don't Reset the Developer and Distribution Certificates in Signing Identities.